# Libgdx область нажатия в не кнопки?

Tags: java, libgdx

```
Skin skin = new Skin();
        skin.add("simpleButton", new TextureRegion(atlas.findRegion("Simpl")));
        TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.newDrawable("simpleButton", Color.DARK_GRAY);
        textButtonStyle.down = skin.newDrawable("simpleButton", Color.DARK_GRAY);
        textButtonStyle.over = skin.newDrawable("simpleButton", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        textButtonStyle.font = font24;

      
        final Group group = new Group();// группа для кнопок
        
        final TextButton pausedButton = new TextButton("Pause", textButtonStyle);
        final TextButton exitButton = new TextButton("Exit", textButtonStyle);


 pausedButton.setPosition(0, 40);
        exitButton.setPosition(0, 0);
        group.addActor(pausedButton);  // засунем все кнопки в группу
        group.addActor(exitButton);
        group.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 140, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 80);   // перемещаем всю группу кнопок целиком
        stage.addActor(group);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Код выше выводит на экран кнопки, но при нажатии они не срабатывают, за то если нажать выше кнопки то происходит нажатие

Comment: Попробуйте сразу создать на нужном вам месте без группировки (я с актёрами никогда не работал, но всякое может быть)

Comment: Возможно у тебя какие-то проблемы с камерой и вьюпортом. Возможно ты менял размер окна и не обновил вьюпорт